# Having troubles setting up Sentry on .NET 7 project

Tags: .net, sentry

I'm trying to pick up new Sentry Sdk (have used extension for webBuilder before) but now I'm stuck...

Doing as per documentation:

my Program.cs file

```
            Sentry.SentrySdk.Init(o => o.Dsn = "mydsn");

            try
            {
                throw new Exception("Test sentry ex");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Sentry.SentrySdk.CaptureException(ex);
            }
```

this works

if I move my dsn to appsettings like this

```
"Sentry": {
    "Dsn": "mydsn"
  },
```

it does not work

And it doesn't work either way if I remove the try/catch and throw some random unhandled exception somewhere in my code. But it should, right?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SentrySdk.Init` is defined on the [`Sentry` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sentry). It's unaware of `application.json` and the `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` and friends.

For that to work, you have to use the `WebHost` extension method. That's in the [`Sentry.AspNetCore` package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sentry.AspNetCore). And instead of calling `SentrySdk.Init` statically, you use the `UseSentry` extension method on `WebHostBuilder`.

E.g; with minimal API:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.WebHost.UseSentry();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSentryTracing();
```

With that, option you configure on `application.json` are automatically picked up.

Sentry has docs on the ASP.NET Core integration here: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/guides/aspnetcore/